# JavaScript/Jquery duplicate function not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

been staring blankly at my screen for a few hours, and thought it would be best to see if someone can identify what exactly's gone wrong with my functions. I essentially have two duplicate functions (the initial that is working, and the second that has been duplicated to perform the same functionality, but retrieve seperate entities, but isn't functioning at all). I can't seem to identify if I mis-referenced something in my second function, or something is simply out of place, so any assistance is appreciated.

Initial part of my project references this array:

```
var index;    

var topics = [      
    {title: "Football Topics", followers: 280, articles: 5, posts: [
        {postId: 101, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content", replies:[
            {replyId: 1, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content"},
        ]},
    ]}
];
```

Following functions are what is calling the show__ functions, topicOnClick is called in a previous function that successfully displays showSingleTopic(), so I'm assuming that topicOnClick2() is the issue

```
function topicOnClick (node, topic){
    'use strict';
    node.on("click", function() {
        showSingleTopic(topic);
    });
}

function topicOnClick2 (node, topic){
    'use strict';
    node.on("click", function() {
        showComments(topic);
    });
}





function getSingleTopic(someTopics, topicTitle) {
    return someTopics.find(function (topic) {
        return topic.title === topicTitle;
    });    
}

function getSingleComment(moreTopics, commentTitle) {
    return moreTopics.find(function (topic) {
        return topic.author === commentTitle;
    });    
}

//showSingleTopic

function showSingleTopic (topicDetails){

    'use strict';

    $("#browsePage").hide();
    $("#individualForumPage").show();

    var page = $("#individualForumPage");
    //page.append("<h1>"topicDetails.title"</h1>")

    var individualTopicTable = $("<table class='forumTable'><tr><th>Contents</th><th>Author</th></tr></table>");

    //Looping all topics in variable "topics"
        for (index in topicDetails.posts) {
                        // let's save the current "post" object into a variable for easy-access
                        var post = topicDetails.posts[index]; // we get one post at a time, and put it into "post" variable
        //console test
        console.log(post.postId);
        var row = $("<tr></tr>");
        row.append("<td>" + post.contents + "</td>");
        row.append("<td>" + post.author + "</td>");

        topicOnClick2(row, topics[index]);


        individualTopicTable.append(row);

        }

    page.html(individualTopicTable);



}










    function showComments (commentDetails){

        'use strict';
        alert(commentDetails.author);

        $("#browsePage").hide();
        $("#individualForumPage").hide();
        $("#commentsPage").show();

        var page = $("#commentsPage");
        //page.append("<h1>"topicDetails.title"</h1>")

        var commentTable = $("<table class='forumTable'><tr><th>Author</th><th>Comments</th></tr></table>");



        //Looping all topics in variable "topics"
            for (index in commentDetails.replies) {
                            // let's save the current "post" object into a variable for easy-access
                            var reply = commentDetails.replies[index]; // we get one post at a time, and put it into "reply" variable

            var row = $("<tr></tr>");
            row.append("<td>" + reply.author + "</td>");
            row.append("<td>" + reply.contents + "</td>");


            //topicOnClick(row, topics[index]);


            commentTable.append(row);

            }
        //========================================================================================================================================================
    // End of referenced source code
    //========================================================================================================================================================

    page.html(commentTable);


    }
```

Comment: Let me guess `getSingleComment()` isn't working? I only can guess, as there is too less information and you actually didn't point use to the problem. We don't see where from the functions are called.

You say you have to identical functions. You probably copy pasted it. Are you aware that the attribute `author` is not on the same level as attribute  `title`

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the functions? It looks like h functions themselves are fine.

Comment: I'm well aware that author and title are on different levels, as I'm trying to retrieve things from different level's. Ill update the source now with the functions calling them